# Bootstrap 4 card UI is not working correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, bootstrap-4

Im tried to create some UI for the my university project, But its not working correctly , anyone know how to do that correctly or any ideas  (l[ook my sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFm9Y.png,)) using [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)

I tried to design like this structure

**This is my code**

```css
.icn-img {border-radius: 50%; display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: white; border: 1px solid lightgray;}
.st-rgt-img{ display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: lightgray}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    
    <div class="container">

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">

          <!----------- details------------>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                <div class=""><span class="icn-img"></span></div>
                <div class="ml-2">No </div>
                <div class=" ml-3 mt-1"> <span style="font-weight: bold;">Salon</span></div>
                <div class=" ml-3"> have been created yet</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">

              <div class="api-lst">


                <div class="card  border-danger border-bottom"  >
                  <div class="card-body ">
            

                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                          <div class=""><span class="st-rgt-img"></span> </div>
                          <div class="p-2"> <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">location</h6></div>

                        </div>

                      </div>

                      <div class="col-sm">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                          <div class=""><span class="st-rgt-img"></span> </div>
                          <div class="p-2"> <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">34 salon</h6></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="col-sm">
                     0:32
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm">
                        <div class="card  border-success ">
                          <div class="card-body text-success">
                            <h5 class="card-title">5</h5>
                          </div>
                          <div class="card-footer bg-success border-success">text</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                </div>

              </div>



            </div>
            <div class="w-100"></div>



          </div>
          <!----------- details------------>
        </div></div>
    </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: To broad question, but this is a good start i think.

https://www.bootply.com/Gv859jDU6Q

Comment: Hello @isherwood , I tried to do some UI struction for my project, i want to know how to do   like this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFm9Y.png,

Comment: There really was no need to @mention me, and any new information should go in your question body, not in a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the link

https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/OqwxZa

```css
.icn-img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.st-rgt-img {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: lightgray
}

.api-lst .card:hover{
      transform: scale(1.04);
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <!----------- details------------>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center ">
              <span class="icn-img"></span>
              <div class="ml-2">No </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class=" ml-3 mt-1"> <span style="font-weight: bold;">Salon</span></div>
            <div class=" ml-3"> have been created yet</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="api-lst">
            <div class="card data  border-danger border-bottom">
              <div class="card-body ">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                      <div class=""><span class="st-rgt-img"></span> </div>
                      <div class="p-2">
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">location</h6>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                      <div class=""><span class="st-rgt-img"></span> </div>
                      <div class="p-2">
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">34 salon</h6>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    0:32
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card  border-success ">       
                      <h5 class="">5</h5>
                      <div class="bg-success border-success">text</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>


              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="card  border-danger border-bottom">
              <div class="card-body ">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                      <div class=""><span class="st-rgt-img"></span> </div>
                      <div class="p-2">
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">location</h6>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                      <div class=""><span class="st-rgt-img"></span> </div>
                      <div class="p-2">
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">34 salon</h6>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    0:32
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card  border-success ">       
                      <h5 class="">5</h5>
                      <div class="bg-success border-success">text</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>


              </div>

            </div>
                        <div class="card  border-danger border-bottom">
              <div class="card-body ">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                      <div class=""><span class="st-rgt-img"></span> </div>
                      <div class="p-2">
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">location</h6>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                      <div class=""><span class="st-rgt-img"></span> </div>
                      <div class="p-2">
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">34 salon</h6>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    0:32
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card  border-success ">       
                      <h5 class="">5</h5>
                      <div class="bg-success border-success">text</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>


              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="w-100"></div>



        </div>
        <!----------- details------------>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```